# Attempted import error: 'useUpdate' is not exported from 'react-three-fiber'

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm getting this error Attempted import error: 'useUpdate' is not exported from 'react-three-fiber'.
I update the versions of all dependencies and after that, I'm facing this issue
these are dependencies

```
    "dependencies": {
    "@react-three/drei": "^3.11.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "dat.gui": "^0.7.7",
    "drei": "^2.2.21",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-three-fiber": "^6.0.13",
    "three": "^0.126.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
```

and here is the imported dependencies code

```
    import * as THREE from 'three';
    import {OrbitControls} from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls';
    import { Canvas, extend, useFrame, useLoader, useThree,useUpdate  } from 'react-three-fiber';
    import circleImg from '././../circle.png';
    import { Suspense, useCallback, useMemo, useRef } from 'react';
```

Comment: Seems to have been removed in v6.0.0: https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber/blob/702fc6c6501c57d762d63b0b3f9bb0ea0e200f17/markdown/changelog.md#removal-of-useupdate